dlopen doesn't work well on Android for Vulkan custom layer
I have a custom layer called memory_layer that collects memory information. Here is what I want to achieve:

Use memory_layer in my Vulkan program. The Vulkan loader loads libmemory_layer.so into memory when vkCreateInstance is called.
The program runs, and memory_layer collects memory information.
Use dlopen and dlsym to get the memory_info_write_out function handle from libmemory_layer.so:

void *handle = dlopen("libmemory_layer.so", RTLD_LAZY);
void (*memory-info-write-out)(const char*) = (void (*)(const char*)) dlsym(handle, "memory-info-write-out");


Call memory_info_write_out to write the memory information to a file. This function is called before vkDestroyInstance.

This process works on Linux perfectly.
But not on Android, memory-info-write-out can not write the information collected by custom_layers.
Investigation on Android:
After vkCreateInstance(1), I checked the memory map of the app thread:
...
6c8a6cc000-6c8ad57000 r-xp 00000000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
6c8ad57000-6c8ad58000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
6c8ad58000-6c8ad7c000 r--p 0068b000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
6c8ad7c000-6c8ad7d000 rw-p 006af000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
...

The thread loaded libmemory_layer.so into memory.
After dlopen(3), I checked the memory map again:
...
6c8562f000-6c85cba000 r-xp 00000000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
6c85cba000-6c85cbb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
6c85cbb000-6c85cdf000 r--p 0068b000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
6c85cdf000-6c85ce0000 rw-p 006af000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
...
6c8a6cc000-6c8ad57000 r-xp 00000000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
6c8ad57000-6c8ad58000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
6c8ad58000-6c8ad7c000 r--p 0068b000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
6c8ad7c000-6c8ad7d000 rw-p 006af000 fe:07 4206502                        /data/local/debug/vulkan/libmemory_layer.so
...

This suggests that dlopen created a new context instead of using the existing one(?).
Questions:

Is dlopen the correct way to call functions in Vulkan layers on Android?
How can I ensure that dlopen uses the existing context instead of creating a new one?

I don't know if dlopen the perfect way to call some function in layers. But I do need to do this.
Research:

dlopen on Android is implemented by BIONIC, which differs from GNU on Linux. dlopen() fails on Android but works on Linux
This might be related to parameters used in dlopen: dlopen and implicit library loading: two copies of the same library I am unable to change the dlopen mode in Vulkan-Loader. I have tried various combinations of modes in my dlopen function, but they did not work.

This question is similar to some others but not exactly the same.

Expose a custom Vulkan extension, and load it via the standard layer loading mechanism to avoid the dlopen() messing about.

Thank you! I have tried this. This works when I add a custom function in layer and expose it in vkGetDeviceProcAddr.
I will use I vkGetDeviceProcAddr to replace dlopen.
But it doesn't when using vkGetInstanceProcAddr. I am still a little confused. Is there some related Docs about this. I can't find them :( .
Thanks again!

If your layer is seeing the vkGetInstanceProcAddr() function call (i.e. not being stripped by the loader), then what's returned is up to your layer code.
